# Differentiable Functions - Approximate Computation

Tags: real-analysis

Write the formulas for approximate computation of the following values:
( $\sin \frac {\pi}{6} +\alpha$) for values of $\alpha$ near 0;
( $\sin 30^\circ +\alpha^\circ$) for values of $\alpha$ near 0;
( $\cos \frac {\pi}{4} +\alpha$) for values of $\alpha$ near 0;
( $\sin 45^\circ +\alpha^\circ$) for values of $\alpha$ near 0;

My friend gave me this hint: Use the formula y is approximately equal to $f'(x_0)$$(x-x_0)$+$f(x_0)$, in this case since you're searching for values near 0 you will have to set $x_0=0$, hence $f'(0)x+f(0)$.

But I'm having hard times to go further.

Comment: So, you have to figure out what $f$ to use, and what $x_0$ to use. Let's look at the first question. You know the value of $\sin(\pi/6)$, right? and also the value of $g(\pi/6)$, where $g$ is the derivative of the sine function? That should tell you what $f$ you want and what $x_0$ you want, since your formula involves $f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Got it Gerry. Thank you!

Comment: Good. Now, let me encourage you to write it up and post it here as an answer.